# application.properties outside jar file how to

Tags: java, spring-boot, classpath

As stated in [spring-boot-reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html):

> On your application classpath (e.g. inside your jar) you can have an
>   application.properties that provides a sensible default property value
>   for name. When running in a new environment, an application.properties
>   can be provided outside of your jar that overrides the name

I place a duplicated application.properties with overridden name on the same path as jar file, however when running the application with:

```
java -jar target/myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The name value is not overridden, it still refers to the one inside application.properties inside jar file. I also tried:

```
java -Dspring.config.location=/target/application.properties -jar target/myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

But it does not work, please help.

**Edit**

When I change the current directory to `target` and run it, it works.

```
java -jar myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Why? Why cannot be outside the path and run it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are trying to launch the jar from another folder: spring boot looks for files/folder relative your current folder.

You can:

1) copy `application.properties` either in `./` or `./config/`, relative to your current folder.

2) Or specify `-Dspring.config.location`:

```
$ java -Dspring.config.location=target/application.properties -jar target/myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

You spelt `config` as `conig`, should work if you spell it right.