# MultipartException when deploying on ECS - Spring 1.5.15.RELEASE

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ecs

I am facing a very strange behavior. I am packing up my jar into a container to deploy it on ECS, however, it seems like my application.yaml is not taking effect when it comes to define the **max-file-size** to **100M**.

oddly it works just fine when launch the application either locally or by executing the fat jar.

Here's my **application.yaml**

```
spring:
  http.multipart:
    max-file-size: 100MB
    max-request-size: 100MB
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-Dspring.profiles.active=prod","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

**The error on AWS**

```
{
  "timestamp": 1535489967123,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException",
  "message": "Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (43258070) exceeds the configured maximum (10485760)",
  "path": "/fake/path/loader"
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to share jar ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is mostly with you application.yaml not getting packaged correctly.
As an alternative you can use command line override for you spring jar in following fashion :

```
java -jar your-app.jar --spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=100MB --spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=100MB
```

or you can refer to external application file loading as mentioned in this answer :
[External Application Props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427675/application-properties-outside-jar-file-how-to)